# How to create a new array in PHP from existing array values within a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array ($datesandadults) with pairs of values which are the date and the number of people:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [thedate] => April 9, 2016 
            [theadults] => 6
        ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
            [thedate] => April 10, 2016 
            [theadults] => 9 
        )
...
```

I need to modify thedate value then put everything back into a new similar structured array. my code doesn't work, all it gives is:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => date 
    [1] => adults 
    [thedate] => 2016-04-09 
    [adults] => )
```

The code I am using is:

```
$final_results = array('thedate','adults');

foreach ($datesandadults as $res2) {
    foreach( $res2 as $key => $value) {
        if ($key=='thedate') {
            $actualtime=strtotime($value);
            $value = date('Y-m-d', $actualtime);
        }

        $final_results[thedate] = $res2->thedate;
        $final_results[adults] = $res2->adults;
    }
}
```

I know my current code is nonsense but maybe will give an idea what I need..

Comment: You might try using `slice()`, which takes an element out of one array and returns it. The implementation would be `$arrayA[$i] = slice($arrayB, $i, 1);` where `$i` is the current key and the `1` is the number of elements (objects) you want to take out of the first array.

Comment: That code does not give that output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of objects, not arrays. You need to loop through the objects, creating a new array. You can access the object properties directly, so you do not need the interior `foreach` loop.

```
// initialize empty result array
$final_results = []; // use array() for PHP < 5.4

foreach ($datesandadults as $res2) {

   // convert original date value
   $actualtime = strtotime($res2->thedate);
   $date_value = date('Y-m-d', $actualtime);

   // create new object with updated values
   $new_object = (object) array(
       'thedate' => $date_value,
       'theadults' => $res2->theadults
   );

   // add new object to result array
   $final_results[] = $new_object;
}
```

Comment: thank you this works fine, I prefer the Object method

Answer (score 0):

First, you may want `$final_results` to be an empty array, so:

```
$final_results = array();
```

Then, you may want to restructure your second loop, so it gets every object from the first one, takes the needed information, and then put it back in the new one. Like this:

```
foreach ($datesandadults as $res2) {
  $thedate = '';
  $theadults = '';
  foreach( $res2 as $key => $value) {
    if ($key=='thedate') {
        $actualtime=strtotime($value);
        $thedate = date('Y-m-d', $actualtime);
    }else if($key=='theadults'){
        $theadults = $value;
    }
  }
  $final_results[] = array(
    'thedate'=>$thedate,
    'theadults'=>$theadults
  );
}
```

Or just skip the second loop and access the values directly